# Complexity and Time consumption while executing the sql query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with over 200 million records and trying to get a result in a single query and it took around 1.5 hours to execute the following query.

My table data:

```
+---------+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| cust_id | product_id | p_a | p_b | p_c |
+---------+------------+-----+-----+-----+
|       1 | a          |   1 |   0 |   0 |
|       1 | b          |   0 |   2 |   0 |
|       1 | a          |   1 |   0 |   0 |
|       1 | c          |   0 |   0 |   3 |
|       2 | a          |   1 |   0 |   0 |
|       2 | c          |   0 |   0 |   3 |
|       2 | c          |   0 |   0 |   3 |
|       3 | b          |   0 |   1 |   0 |
+---------+------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

I need the following result:

```
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+------+-------+
| No.ofcustomers | p_a | p_b | p_c | P_ab | P_abc |
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+------+-------+
|              3 |   0 |   1 |   0 |    0 |     1 |
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+------+-------+
```

p_a returns the number of customers who bougth only product a. Similarly, p_b,p_c, p_ab, p_abc.

So far, I have written the following query which gives me the output. But, is there any way that i could decrease the time taken to execute the query. I mean 1.5 hour is realatively very high for any query.

```
WITH CTE AS
       (
    SELECT CUST_ID, SUM(P_A) AS PA, SUM(P_B) AS PB, SUM(P_C) AS PC
      FROM TABLE
      GROUP BY CUST_ID), CTE1 AS
       (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_ID) AS NOOFCUSTOMERS, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN PA >= 1 AND PB = 0 AND PC = 0 THEN CUST_ID END)) AS P_A, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN PA = 0 AND PB >= 1 AND PC = 0 THEN CUST_ID END)) AS P_B, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN PA = 0 AND PB = 0 AND PC >= 1 THEN CUST_ID END)) AS P_C, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN PA >= 1 AND PB >= 1 AND PC = 0 THEN CUST_ID END)) AS P_AB, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN PA <> 0 AND PB <> 0 AND PC <> 0 THEN CUST_ID END)) AS P_ABC
      FROM CTE)
  SELECT *
    FROM CTE1;
```

Comment: This seems to be a "reporting query" that processes a massive amount of data, not a "transactional query" that processes a minimal subset of data. A reporting query is bound to be slow.

Comment: I assume you already have the covering index on (cust_id, p_a, p_b, p_c). This is the first step in optimization.

Comment: Also, if this is a warehouse, your account or query may be subject to throttling and workload controls defined for the database.  What your your Db2-server Operating system (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows,  cloud) ?  Have you used the Query Optimization tools that come with your platform+version of Db2 ?

Comment: Do you really need live information during the day? Maybe you can produce a materialized view that is computed at night, and during the day you get information from last night.

Comment: How long does it take to run the first CTE?  I am guessing that is what is driving the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the query to:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT CUST_ID, SUM(P_A) AS PA, SUM(P_B) AS PB, SUM(P_C) AS PC
      FROM TABLE
      GROUP BY CUST_ID
     )
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NOOFCUSTOMERS, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PA >= 1 AND PB = 0 AND PC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_A, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PA = 0 AND PB >= 1 AND PC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_B, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PA = 0 AND PB = 0 AND PC >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_C, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PA >= 1 AND PB >= 1 AND PC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_AB, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PA <> 0 AND PB <> 0 AND PC <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_ABC
FROM CTE;
```

The first CTE is summarizing by customer id, so these are already unique.  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is more expensive than other aggregation functions, so that might be hurting performance.

Comment: It worked like a charm!!! But, why does count(distinct) is expensive than other aggregation functions? Could you please explain how does both work in a short note?

Comment: @saikumarvoruganti . . . `count(distinct)` has to do a lot more work to remove duplicates.